# Change Googlebot crawl rate 2019

Tags: search, console, web-crawler, googlebot, rate

In the new (Sept 2019) Google Search Console, how do I limit the crawl rate?

All found searches on this topic point to https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en which I believe describes how to do this using the old Search Console.

I used to be able to use both the OLD and NEW Search Console, but it appears that I can only use the NEW one now.

In the NEW one, the SETTINGS area does NOT have a Crawl Rate section.

Comment: Google does throttle itself, but only after it finds that it's overwhelming the server and causing slow responses. They are causing slow responses for our e-commerce customers as well, who we are losing (5-10% drop) due to a slow responding website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the OLD Search Console Crawl-Rate Settings cannot be reached from the NEW Search Console, there is a direct link to get you there.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/settings

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. The page shows an "add property" button but when clicking through, I can see my properties but there's no way accessing the crawl rate pane.

Comment: Make sure it's pulling put the right Google account. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts in your browser, this link will sometimes load under the wrong one. I tried it again, and I get a "select property", like I should, and it works for me. I always do this in CHROME, as Google is usually happier with CHROME.

Comment: My properties are empty. When click on "Add property now" it does list all my properties but there's no way to "add" them. This behaviour is in a freshly logged in incognito window in chrome.

Comment: I have not had luck using incognito mode in Chrome with Google sites. The Google home page makes it super easy to switch accounts, I just use that. I found that I have to be logged into Chrome (not just Google) as the Search Console account owner.

Comment: Been looking/asking around and it seems that it has something to do with how the property is verified or maybe if multiple verification methods are used or not. It also could be if the domain includes https or not. Weird